# regex string between comma or parenthese but not contains dot

Tags: regex

my goal is to have a regex, witch captures the following:

- any strings between '(' and ',' boundaries excluding
- any strings between ',' and ',' boundaries excluding
- any strings between ',' and ')' boundaries excluding
- the founded substring doesn't contain any dots

F. e.:

- '(xxxx,' => valid
- '(xxxx)' => valid
- '(xxx.yyy,' => invalid

For the substring excluding the boundaries I have this regex:

```
(?<=[\(\,])(.*?)(?=[\)\,])
```

It works fine.

Now I wanted to extend it to deny any strings containing dot like this:

```
(?<=[\(\,])((?!\.).*?)(?=[\)\,])
```

But it doesnt' filter out the strings with dot, f. e. this remains valid:

'(xxxx.yyyy)'

How should I adjust the regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negated character class:

```sh
(?<=[(,])([^.]*?)(?=[),])
```

`[^.]` will match any character that is not a dot.

Also note that there is no need to escape characters like `(, ). ,` etc inside a character class i.e. `[...]`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?<=[(,])[^(),.]*(?=[),])
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/2iekyP/1).

**Explanation**

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=` | look behind to see if there is: |
| `[(,]` | any character of: '(', ',' |
| `)` | end of look-behind |
| `[^(),.]*` | any character except: '(', ')', ',', '.' (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `(?=` | look ahead to see if there is: |
| `[),]` | any character of: ')', ',' |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |